# clarifying Treasury basis carry

Tags: fixed-income, bond-yields, treasuries, basis

I'm going through the classic *The Treasury Bond Basis* by Galen Burghardt. In the book he states, "...if the yield curve has a positive slope, carry for someone who is long bonds and short futures is positive."

I'm not able to arrive at the same conclusion. By being long bond you earn running yield - repo. On the other hand your short futures position will have an equivalent negative carry? The future price is a direct function of the cost of carrying the bond? Hence, net - net you should earn zero carry on a day to day basis? Your long position has positive carry, but your short futures position will grind higher in price and hence offset your bond carry.

What am I missing?

Comment: is this a joke? @nbbo2